# v-for and state management issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a list of items rendered with v-for. I want each item to have a "?" that is clickable to show a modal containing a description for that specific item. My issue right now is that when the "?" is clicked, it shows the modal for every item in the v-for. How do i solve this?

```
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  :key="index"
>
  <div>
    {{ item.name }}
    <div>
      <span @click="itemModal = true">    
        ?
      </span>
      <div v-show="itemModal">
        {{ item.description }}
        <button @click="itemModal = false">
          Close modal
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemModal: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, all your items modals will have the same name, you should use that uniq index you have.

Comment: I think that having a modal would be a better solution. You can store the index of the item when clicking on the ?  tag and the fill the description. You don't need to have as many modals as items.

Comment: Good idea. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting `items` from? Inside the data method, you have only `itemModal`

Comment: @AndresPaul I went with your solution, works very well. Thanks for the help. I will post the solution, as soon as Stackoverflow allows me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `itemModal` property is share with all items currently, so you need one modal status for each item.

eg. you can create a `toggle` method to update an `array` of modal status:

```js
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  :key="index"
>
  <div>
    {{ item.name }}
    <div>
      <span @click="toggle(index)">    
        ?
      </span>
      <div v-show="itemModal[index]">
        {{ item.description }}
        <button @click="toggle(index)">
          Close modal
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemModal: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(index) {
      this.$set(this.itemModal, index, !this.itemModal[index])
    }
  }
}
```

**nb:** an array (or an object) is not reactive in depth, so we have to use `Vue.$set` (cf. [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties))